# How can I shift coffee stains out of fabric?

Tags: accidents

I spilled my coffee all over my cotton shirt. Will it stain if I let it dry? It's not white so I can't just bleach it. Or will it come out in an ordinary wash?

Comment: each fabric responds to different chemicals. Can you post the make-up of the shirt?

Comment: I like your [tag:accidents] tag. Could also have been tagged "oops."

Comment: @JustinC added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

howstuffworks.com has complete directions for removing coffee from all kinds of materials. Here is what they say about Cotton.

> **Cotton and Linen**
>  Follow these steps to remove coffee stains from Cotton and Linen:
>
> - Blot up excess.
> - Pretreat (the method of applying a stain-removing agent directly to    the stained area before laundering) with Shout Liquid Laundry Stain
>     Remover, then launder immediately.
> - If that is not possible, soak the stain in a solution of 1 quart warm    water and 1/2 teaspoon dishwashing detergent for 15 minutes.
> - Rinse well with water.
> - Next, sponge the stain with rubbing alcohol.
> - Rinse and allow to dry.
> - If the stain remains, use an enzyme presoak (follow directions on    label).
> - Rinse well with water and dry.
> - Launder as soon as possible.
>
> Another method that has worked:
>
> - Stretch the stained area over a bowl and secure with a rubber band.
> - Pour boiling water through the stain from a height of 2 to 3 feet.    Stand back to avoid splatters.
> - Although cotton and linen can stand boiling water, some of the    finishes and colors used on the fabrics might be damaged by such
>     harsh treatment.
> - Be sure to test on an inconspicuous corner first. (If coffee    contained cream and any greasy stain remains, follow procedures to
>     Remove Milk and Cream.)

There are more directions for other fabrics and materials [here](http://home.howstuffworks.com/how-to-remove-coffee-stains.htm).

Answer (score 3):

Coffee stains on cotton fabric can be treated using standard laundry strain removing products like Spray-and-Wash and OxiClean. The former has worked well for me in the past. Spray it on the stain and let it sit for a day or so before putting it in the wash.

As with any laundry product, it's a good idea to spot test to ensure your garment is colorfast.